# Kendo Grid drag shadow automatically comes

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

We are working on a kendo grid with multiselection and need to show a alertbox on grid cell mouse click.In our case alert will come but a mouse drag shadow is also there.I need that shadow but only in mouse drag.

Comment: I have created a demo.Please check this demo http://jsfiddle.net/jssacwgf/ .Click any of the cell then shadow will come.How to avoid that shadow.I have fixed this issue with grid.refresh() but it also refresh the css.

Answer (score 0):

I have update code.

```
'http://jsfiddle.net/jssacwgf/2/' updated link
```

i hope you like this.

Comment: thanks.That i have fixed by adding mouse up event dynamically (calling e.mouseup();)